# Remove Bazel distribution URI as a package source

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, ppa

I added Bazel distribution URI as a package source using the following instructions from their [website](https://www.bazel.io/versions/master/docs/install.html):

```
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt/doc/apt-key.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bazel
$ sudo apt-get upgrade bazel
```

Installation went fine, but I keep getting these annoying messages from `apt-get` whenever I update or install a new package:

```
N: Ignoring file 'bazel.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

So I decided to uninstall bazel and install it through the ubuntu installer, however this did not get rid of the `apt-get` message since the distribution URI is still in the list although the package is uninstalled.

How can I remove it from the list? From the question [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) it seems like the following might work, but before doing it I wanted to make sure I'm not removing ppas for other packages.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt
```

Could you let me know if I'm on the right track? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you mistyped the `tee` command when you originally did it - the filename is wrong. APT is complaining because the files in `sources.list.d` must have the extension `.list` and yours has `.lis`

You can delete the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.lis
```

The errors will go away :)

The `add-apt-repository --remove` command would work (delete the file for you), if `add-apt-repository` could match the description `ppa:http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt` to a file, but that will not work here, I believe, since the filename is not valid. Rather than using `echo` and `tee`, you may want to use `add-apt-repository` to add ppas, as it will just error out if you make a typo (unless you unluckily type the real name of a ppa that is not the ppa you really want!) rather than giving you a broken file.